# Php Visualizar Colunas

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Tenho duas colunas A e B com palavras variadas, quero remover, toda a linha de A e B que na coluna B tenha menos que 8 caracteres.

como faço isso em php?

Comment: exemplo:  testando|12345678 - porem quero visualizar apenas os que contem 8 acima caracteres depois do |

Comment: Você quer montar um Query que só exiba as linhas onde B possui mais de 8 caracteres? Ou quer excluir do banco as linhas que possuem menos de 8?

Comment: Cuidado com a pergunta pois remover a linha pode dar sentido de Delete

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar as funções [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) e [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) para te auxiliar.

A função strlen retorna o tamanho de uma string
Já função explode criar uma array dividindo a string (2º parâmetro) baseado no delimitador (1º parâmetro ).

Exemplo:

```
$string = " testando|12345678 ";

if( strlen(explode("|", $string)[1]) < 8 )
    remover_linha();
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é mais eficiente e simples se executado pelo mysql

> $query = "SELECT id, A, B FROM tabela WHERE
>   CHAR_LENGTH(B) >=8";
>
> $recordset = mysqli_query($query, $link);

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o [strlen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php).

```
if (strlen($palavra) > 8) {
//aqui exibi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Busca os dados na tabela
$query = "SELECT id, colunaA, colunaB FROM tabela";
//Executa a query
$result = mysqli_query($query, $link);
//Cria uma variávelaleatória para armazenar os IDs das linhas a serem removidas
$array[] = '';
//Rotina de repetição para percorrer todos os resultados
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //Verifica se a coluna B tem menos de 8 caracteres
    if(strlen($row['colunaB']) < 8){
        //Se a coluna B tiver menos de 8 caracteres, adiciona o ID da linha em questão na array
        $array[] = $row['id'];
    }
}
//Agora a array contém apenas os IDs das linhas que precisam ser removidas
foreach ($array as $key) {
    //Cria a query com um ID de cada vez
    $query = "DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id = $key";
    //Executa a query removendo uma linha de cada vez
    mysqli_query($query);
}
```

Acho que assim vai. Tentei fazer de uma forma fácil de entender.

Answer (score 0):

Para listar apenas as linhas que contenham a coluna B com mais de 8 caracteres:

```
<?php 
    $pdo = Connection::Conexao(); // Conexão com o banco
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABELA";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);           
    $query->execute();

    while ($dados = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        if(strlen($dados["coluna_B"]) > 8) {
            // mostrando coluna A e B somente se B tiver mais de 8 caracteres
            echo $dados["coluna_A"]." - ".$dados["coluna_B"]."<br />";
        } else {

            // você também pode inserir aqui um código para deletar os registros onde
            // b for menor que 8
        }
    }
?>
```